Dash Mechanism is very glitchy in unity photon fusion multiplayer
I am working on a dash mechanism for 2D multiplayer game in unity with photon fusion. My requirement is that when the player presses LShift, they will move at a lower speed and a UI to charge the slider will be shown. The player can hold LMb to their desired charge and release to dash. Later which I want my player to move with default speed. Also the player by pressing RMb, can cancel the charge on or before charging so that he/she doesn't dash and move with default speed.
Everything works completely fine expect for the dashing part as it gives a jerky movement especially on the client. The below is the code I have for the same.
using UnityEngine;
using Fusion;

public class Player : NetworkBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody2D PlayerRigidbody;

    private float _dashSpeed = DataUtils.DashSpeed; // Speed of the dash
    private float _lastDashTime = -Mathf.Infinity;
    private Vector2 _movement;

    public float minDuration; // Minimum ability duration
    public float maxDuration = DataUtils.MaxDashDuration; // Maximum ability duration

    public CharacterCanvasBase Canvas;

    public override void FixedUpdateNetwork()
    {
        // player direction input to dash
        _movement = DirectionInput;

        // below is psuedo code
        if (LShiftPressed)
        {
            StartCoroutine(Dash());
        }
    }

    private IEnumerator Dash()
    {
        _lastDashTime = Time.time;

        Vector2 startDashPosition = PlayerRigidbody.position;
        Vector2 dashDirection = _movement.normalized;

        // Check if the player is moving. If not, dash downward
        if (dashDirection == Vector2.zero)
        {
            dashDirection = Vector2.down; // Or any default direction you prefer
        }

        // Get charge level to determine dash speed and possibly duration
        float chargeLevel = Canvas.GetComponent<HexCanvas>().ChargeController.GetChargeProgress();
        float adjustedDuration = minDuration + (maxDuration - minDuration) * Mathf.Pow(chargeLevel, 2);
        float dashEndTime = Time.time + adjustedDuration;

        while (Time.time < dashEndTime)
        {
            float dashProgress = (Time.time - _lastDashTime) / adjustedDuration;
            RPC_DashMove(startDashPosition, dashDirection, dashProgress, _dashSpeed * adjustedDuration);
            yield return null;
        }
    }

    [Rpc(RpcSources.All, RpcTargets.All)]
    public void RPC_DashMove(Vector2 startDashPosition, Vector2 dashDirection, float dashProgress, float dashSpeed)
    {
        PlayerRigidbody.MovePosition(Vector2.Lerp(startDashPosition, startDashPosition + dashDirection * dashSpeed, dashProgress));
    }
}

I tried interpolating the NetworkRigidbody2d component to all the available interpolation data sources(Auto, snapshots, predicted, no interpolation) in photon fusion.
Initially, I have tried DashMove to run locally. But while dashing, the state authority overrides the player position especially on the client. So I made it an RPC. The thing with RPCs is that they're not tick based instead time based. Potentially, this jerkiness is coz of trying to dash using an RPC.
Later I have also tried making the state authority to handle the dash locally which should be synced across all the clients. But it is snapping the player to the final dash position.
What is the right approach?

Sending that many rpcs for a simple dash seems troublesome.  Why not send one rpc for dash start and one for dash end, or at a slower interval.  If you have 60fps, you are sending 60 RPCs a second.  Also, you are using a physics method to move, but not during the physics update.  Wait until the physics frame before moving the rigidbody.

The problem is the use of RPCs and Coroutines for something that should be done inside of FixedUpdateNetwork. Both RPCs and Coroutines do not play well with the predict-rollback model that Fusion uses, which leads to the stuttery movement that you see here.

Your code should instead set a [Networked] dash timer, and dash whenever that value is > 0, decrementing as needed.
Your Canvas.GetComponent<HexCanvas>().ChargeController call also can produce issues, especially if the ChargeController is not [Networked]. Make sure it uses a NetworkBehaviour and a [Networked] variable. If you can't (since it's a scene object), do the charge logic inside of your Player class (inside of FixedUpdateNetwork()!), and just update the canvas with the current charge state / values. I did not do this in my example code.
Use NetworkRigidbody2D instead of just a normal Rigidbody2D, to properly synchronize the velocity. And actually use the velocity, instead of interpolating between two positions.

Fixed example code would look something like:
using UnityEngine;
using Fusion;

public class Player : NetworkBehaviour
{
    // Added networked variables
    [Networked] private float DashTimer { get; set; }
    [Networked] private Vector2 DashDirection { get; set; }
    
    // Replaced with networked rigidbody
    public NetworkRigidbody2D PlayerRigidbody;

    // Misc variables
    private float _dashSpeed = DataUtils.DashSpeed; // Speed of the dash
    public float minDuration; // Minimum ability duration
    public float maxDuration = DataUtils.MaxDashDuration; // Maximum ability duration
    public CharacterCanvasBase Canvas;

    public override void FixedUpdateNetwork()
    {
        if (GetInput(out YourInputClass input)) {
            bool shiftPressed = input...;
            Vector2 movement = input...;

            HandleDashing(movement, shiftPressed);
        }
    }

    private void HandleDashing(Vector2 movement, bool shiftPressed)
    {
        if (DashTimer <= 0 && shiftPressed) {
            // This is the start of a dash
            DashDirection = movement.normalized;

            // Check if the player is moving. If not, dash downward
            if (DashDirection == Vector2.zero)
            {
                DashDirection = Vector2.down;
            }

            // Get charge level to determine dash speed and possibly duration
            float chargeLevel = Canvas.GetComponent<HexCanvas>().ChargeController.GetChargeProgress();
            DashTimer = minDuration + (maxDuration - minDuration) * Mathf.Pow(chargeLevel, 2);
        }

        if (DashTimer > 0) {
            // We are currently inside of a dash
            PlayerRigidbody.Velocity = DashDirection * _dashSpeed;
            DashTimer -= Runner.DeltaTime;
        }
    }
}

